# host and nslookup can resolve hosts, while dig and systemd-resolved return NXDOMAIN

Tags: linux, dns, arch-linux, nslookup, dig

I am trying to connect to a public WiFi. As it is common (at least in Europe), the WiFi is an open network, but after connecting for the first time, the local DNS server already resolves any domain names correctly, but any outgoing requests to port 80 are answered with a redirect to a login page and any outgoing to requests to other ports are blocked. Only after confirming the terms and conditions on that login page can I actually make outgoing connections to the internet.

In my case, the login page is hosted under the domain `hotsplots.de`. However, trying to open that page in the browser gives me an `ERR_NAME_NOT_RESOLVED`. I am on Arch Linux, and my system uses NetworkManager and systemd-resolved.

my `/etc/resolv.conf` contains a typical systemd-resolved configuration:

```
nameserver 127.0.0.53
options edns0 trust-ad
search hotspot
```

`systemd-resolve --status` shows the following:

```
Global
           Protocols: +LLMNR +mDNS -DNSOverTLS DNSSEC=no/unsupported
    resolv.conf mode: stub
Fallback DNS Servers: 1.1.1.1#cloudflare-dns.com 9.9.9.9#dns.quad9.net 8.8.8.8#dns.google 2606:4700:4700::1111#cloudflare-dns.com 2620:fe::9#dns.quad9.net 2001:4860:4860::8888#dns.google

Link 2 (wlan0)
    Current Scopes: DNS LLMNR/IPv4 LLMNR/IPv6 mDNS/IPv4 mDNS/IPv6
         Protocols: +DefaultRoute +LLMNR +mDNS -DNSOverTLS DNSSEC=no/unsupported
Current DNS Server: 192.168.44.1
       DNS Servers: 192.168.44.1
        DNS Domain: hotspot

Link 5 (vpn0)
    Current Scopes: none
         Protocols: -DefaultRoute +LLMNR +mDNS -DNSOverTLS DNSSEC=no/unsupported
```

My IP address is `192.168.44.168/22`, and the IP address of the default route and of the DNS server is `192.168.44.1`. My `/etc/systemd/resolved.conf` only contains commented out settings.

Now interestingly, some commands can resolve the host `hotsplots.de`, while others cannot:

`systemd-resolve hotsplots.de`:

```
hotsplots.de: Name 'hotsplots.de' not found
```

```
Jan 02 16:39:36 cdauth-atl systemd-resolved[11509]: Got message type=method_call sender=:1.121 destination=org.freedesktop.resolve1 path=/org/freedesktop/resolve1 interface=org.freedesktop.resolve1.Manager member=ResolveHostname  cookie=2 reply_cookie=0 signature=isit error-name=n/a error-message=n/a
Jan 02 16:39:36 cdauth-atl systemd-resolved[11509]: idn2_lookup_u8: hotsplots.de → hotsplots.de
Jan 02 16:39:36 cdauth-atl systemd-resolved[11509]: Sent message type=method_call sender=n/a destination=org.freedesktop.DBus path=/org/freedesktop/DBus interface=org.freedesktop.DBus member=GetConnectionUnixProcessID cookie=37 reply_cookie=0 signature=s error-name=n/a error-message=n/a
Jan 02 16:39:36 cdauth-atl systemd-resolved[11509]: Got message type=method_return sender=org.freedesktop.DBus destination=:1.119 path=n/a interface=n/a member=n/a  cookie=24 reply_cookie=37 signature=u error-name=n/a error-message=n/a
Jan 02 16:39:36 cdauth-atl systemd-resolved[11509]: D-Bus hostname resolution request from client PID 11629 (systemd-resolve) with UID 1000
Jan 02 16:39:36 cdauth-atl systemd-resolved[11509]: Looking up RR for hotsplots.de IN A.
Jan 02 16:39:36 cdauth-atl systemd-resolved[11509]: Looking up RR for hotsplots.de IN AAAA.
Jan 02 16:39:36 cdauth-atl systemd-resolved[11509]: Sent message type=method_call sender=n/a destination=org.freedesktop.DBus path=/org/freedesktop/DBus interface=org.freedesktop.DBus member=AddMatch cookie=38 reply_cookie=0 signature=s error-name=n/a error-message=n/a
Jan 02 16:39:36 cdauth-atl systemd-resolved[11509]: Sent message type=method_call sender=n/a destination=org.freedesktop.DBus path=/org/freedesktop/DBus interface=org.freedesktop.DBus member=GetNameOwner cookie=39 reply_cookie=0 signature=s error-name=n/a error-message=n/a
Jan 02 16:39:36 cdauth-atl systemd-resolved[11509]: Got message type=method_return sender=org.freedesktop.DBus destination=:1.119 path=n/a interface=n/a member=n/a  cookie=26 reply_cookie=39 signature=s error-name=n/a error-message=n/a
Jan 02 16:39:36 cdauth-atl systemd-resolved[11509]: Cache miss for hotsplots.de IN AAAA
Jan 02 16:39:36 cdauth-atl systemd-resolved[11509]: Firing regular transaction 15460 for <hotsplots.de IN AAAA> scope dns on wlan0/* (validate=yes).
Jan 02 16:39:36 cdauth-atl systemd-resolved[11509]: Using feature level UDP+EDNS0 for transaction 15460.
Jan 02 16:39:36 cdauth-atl systemd-resolved[11509]: Using DNS server 192.168.44.1 for transaction 15460.
Jan 02 16:39:36 cdauth-atl systemd-resolved[11509]: Announcing packet size 1472 in egress EDNS(0) packet.
Jan 02 16:39:36 cdauth-atl systemd-resolved[11509]: Emitting UDP, link MTU is 1500, socket MTU is 0, minimal MTU is 40
Jan 02 16:39:36 cdauth-atl systemd-resolved[11509]: Sending query packet with id 15460 of size 41.
Jan 02 16:39:36 cdauth-atl systemd-resolved[11509]: Cache miss for hotsplots.de IN A
Jan 02 16:39:36 cdauth-atl systemd-resolved[11509]: Firing regular transaction 15448 for <hotsplots.de IN A> scope dns on wlan0/* (validate=yes).
Jan 02 16:39:36 cdauth-atl systemd-resolved[11509]: Using feature level UDP+EDNS0 for transaction 15448.
Jan 02 16:39:36 cdauth-atl systemd-resolved[11509]: Using DNS server 192.168.44.1 for transaction 15448.
Jan 02 16:39:36 cdauth-atl systemd-resolved[11509]: Announcing packet size 1472 in egress EDNS(0) packet.
Jan 02 16:39:36 cdauth-atl systemd-resolved[11509]: Emitting UDP, link MTU is 1500, socket MTU is 0, minimal MTU is 40
Jan 02 16:39:36 cdauth-atl systemd-resolved[11509]: Sending query packet with id 15448 of size 41.
Jan 02 16:39:36 cdauth-atl systemd-resolved[11509]: Got message type=method_return sender=org.freedesktop.DBus destination=:1.119 path=n/a interface=n/a member=n/a  cookie=25 reply_cookie=38 signature=n/a error-name=n/a error-message=n/a
Jan 02 16:39:36 cdauth-atl systemd-resolved[11509]: Match type='signal',sender='org.freedesktop.DBus',path='/org/freedesktop/DBus',interface='org.freedesktop.DBus',member='NameOwnerChanged',arg0=':1.121' successfully installed.
Jan 02 16:39:36 cdauth-atl systemd-resolved[11509]: Received dns UDP packet of size 41, ifindex=2, ttl=0, fragsize=0, sender=192.168.44.1, destination=192.168.44.168
Jan 02 16:39:36 cdauth-atl systemd-resolved[11509]: Processing incoming packet of size 41 on transaction 15460 (rcode=NXDOMAIN).
Jan 02 16:39:36 cdauth-atl systemd-resolved[11509]: Not caching negative entry without a SOA record: hotsplots.de IN AAAA
Jan 02 16:39:36 cdauth-atl systemd-resolved[11509]: Regular transaction 15460 for <hotsplots.de IN AAAA> on scope dns on wlan0/* now complete with <rcode-failure> from network (unsigned; non-confidential).
Jan 02 16:39:36 cdauth-atl systemd-resolved[11509]: Received dns UDP packet of size 41, ifindex=2, ttl=0, fragsize=0, sender=192.168.44.1, destination=192.168.44.168
Jan 02 16:39:36 cdauth-atl systemd-resolved[11509]: Processing incoming packet of size 41 on transaction 15448 (rcode=NXDOMAIN).
Jan 02 16:39:36 cdauth-atl systemd-resolved[11509]: Not caching negative entry without a SOA record: hotsplots.de IN A
Jan 02 16:39:36 cdauth-atl systemd-resolved[11509]: Regular transaction 15448 for <hotsplots.de IN A> on scope dns on wlan0/* now complete with <rcode-failure> from network (unsigned; non-confidential).
Jan 02 16:39:36 cdauth-atl systemd-resolved[11509]: Freeing transaction 15460.
Jan 02 16:39:36 cdauth-atl systemd-resolved[11509]: Sent message type=error sender=n/a destination=:1.121 path=n/a interface=n/a member=n/a cookie=40 reply_cookie=2 signature=s error-name=org.freedesktop.resolve1.DnsError.NXDOMAIN error-message=Name 'hotsplots.de' not found
Jan 02 16:39:36 cdauth-atl systemd-resolved[11509]: Sent message type=method_call sender=n/a destination=org.freedesktop.DBus path=/org/freedesktop/DBus interface=org.freedesktop.DBus member=RemoveMatch cookie=41 reply_cookie=0 signature=s error-name=n/a error-message=n/a
Jan 02 16:39:36 cdauth-atl systemd-resolved[11509]: Freeing transaction 15448.
```

`host hotsplots.de 192.168.44.1`:

```
Using domain server:
Name: 192.168.44.1
Address: 192.168.44.1#53
Aliases: 

hotsplots.de has address 92.51.175.170
hotsplots.de mail is handled by 50 mx3.hotsplots.de.
```

`dig @192.168.44.1 hotsplots.de`:

```
; <<>> DiG 9.18.20 <<>> @192.168.44.1 hotsplots.de
; (1 server found)
;; global options: +cmd
;; Got answer:
;; ->>HEADER<<- opcode: QUERY, status: NXDOMAIN, id: 2439
;; flags: qr aa rd ra; QUERY: 1, ANSWER: 0, AUTHORITY: 0, ADDITIONAL: 1

;; OPT PSEUDOSECTION:
; EDNS: version: 0, flags:; udp: 1232
; COOKIE: 980846e96f2fd1a1 (echoed)
;; QUESTION SECTION:
;hotsplots.de.                  IN      A

;; Query time: 5 msec
;; SERVER: 192.168.44.1#53(192.168.44.1) (UDP)
;; WHEN: Tue Jan 02 17:23:45 CET 2024
;; MSG SIZE  rcvd: 53
```

`nslookup hotsplots.de 192.168.44.1`:

```
Server:         192.168.44.1
Address:        192.168.44.1#53

Non-authoritative answer:
Name:   hotsplots.de
Address: 92.51.175.170
```

So `host` and `nslookup` can resolve the hostname, but `dig` and `systemd-resolved` cannot.

If I manually change `/etc/resolv.conf` to `nameserver 192.168.44.1`, the `host` and `nslookup` command start working without specifying the nameserver, but the `dig` command still fails. It seems that the browser also still gives an `ERR_NAME_NOT_RESOLVED` error and running for example `ping hotsplots.de` still fails with `hotsplots.de: Name or service not known`. Only after adding `92.51.175.170 hotsplots.de www.hotsplots.de` to `/etc/hosts`, I was able to open the login page and log in.

After logging in, it turns out that the problem persists. While I can make connections to the public internet and thus use the connection by using a public DNS server, as long as I keep using the local DNS server, `systemd-resolved`, `dig`, my browser and `ping` still complain that they cannot resolve any host names.

I am really confused what is going on here. What is the difference between the requests that `dig` and `host` make? What could be the cause of the problem? How can I investigate this further?

Comment: Does the redirect go to `hotsplots.de` or `www.hotsplots.de`? There may only be a record for www, but some browsers hide it automatically. Take a look at the answers here: https://serverfault.com/questions/501168/ and here: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/612416/. `dig` will not use your `resolv.conf` unless you use `+search`. Try restarting both `systemd-networkd` and `systemd-resolved`. Check if your vpn has added something to resolvconf that is messing with your dns?